# Help with ajax autocomplete by querying the database

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

The question what comes in my mind is whether my query is returning the values from the database or did I miss anything in my code. I have been trying to figure it out but I am unable to understand.

> print_r($tagnames) doesn't print anything on the screen.

This code is part of the controller

```
function get_Names() {
            // Convert the string to the lowercase
            $q = strtolower($this->input->post('q', TRUE));
            if(!$q) {
                return;

            }
            $tagnames[] = $this->autocomplete_model->getData();
            print_r($tagnames);

            echo json_encode($tagnames);

        }
```

I have autocomplete_model.php and this code is part of the model

```
class Autocomplete_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getData() {
        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tags");
        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row->tag_name;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following code in my view

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#tagname" ).autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('generator/get_Names'); ?>",
                        data: { term: $("#tagname").val()},
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data){
                                response(data);
                        }
                    });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are not getting any thing printed in `print_r($tagnames)` then for sure you are not getting any thing from database, first check it out, then look in to client side code.

Comment: in foreach loop `print $row->tag_name` and let me know what is it printing?

Comment: It prints nothing. Can we print from the model ?

Comment: its against the design practice of MVC but for testing its correct.... `print_r($q)` what does it print before the loop?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in the model. It is not printing anything in the model. I tried `echo "hello"` and even that is not printing on the screen. I guess the model is not loading properly.

Comment: is error reporting is turned on in your php settings?

Comment: Yea the error reporting is turned on.

Comment: Then check the model.. and for test after print write the `exit()` function.

Comment: I get the output when `if(!$q) {
                return;

            }`  the return statement is commented out.

Comment: then probably `$this->input->post('q',TRUE)` is not getting any thing.. check what is in `print_r($this->input->post())`.. it might help you.

Comment: It returns nothing. But when I type some letter in the text field, the text field is highlighted with very light greyish color. That means it is recognizing the letters but not sure why it is not able to print the list. Is there any problem in the jquery I have in the view.

Comment: I get the `url is undefined http://localhost/path/to/jquery.autocomplete.js` in `line 350` in the error console of firefox.

Comment: you are not including the `jquery.autocomplete.js` file correctly

Comment: I tried commenting the code for retrieving from the database and just added an array with elements and pull up the list. It works perfectly for that and not when querying the database. Have spent like 6 hours struggling on this... :(

Comment: Then first check your database part and then go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your AJAX call is sending "term" as post data but your get_Names() method is looking for a post parameter of "q". Change one of them and I think you should be good.

Comment: Yes, I have changed 'q' to 'term' and I think there is some response from the server but firebug shows the 500 Internal Server error when I enter some text in the input field.

Comment: My first thought was you have a print_r and an echo outputting the JSON results. But I don't think that would cause a 500 error. 500 error means something is wrong with the server. It could mean a lot of things. Best to check out the log files and see what they say. Sometimes it be logged into the Codeigniter logs too.

Comment: I found the error, it is with the config file of the codeigniter. I have csrf filtering that is causing the error from outputting the result and causing the 500 error